# Material UI TextField multiline fixed quantity of rows

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to define maximum fixed rows to TextField multiline, setting *maxRows* to 5 is not working, finally got infinite rows, is there any way to fix quantity of rows to 5? Thanks

```
<TextField multiline maxRows={5}/>
```

Above is not working.

Comment: Do you mean to prevent the user to add more text after 5 years?

Comment: I think you need to use `rowsMax`, not `maxRows`. If you want to prevent user to add no more than 5 lines, then you may have to make it a `controlledInput`.

Comment: Working with React, getting warning *React does not recognise the 'rowsMax' prop on a DOM element*

Comment: Yes, need to prevent user adding more than 5 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work correctly in the way it was intended. The props `maxRows` and `minRows` control how many *visible* rows are displayed. Thus if you want to have a fixed number of 5 rows always visible (that is 5 rows even when TextField is empty still show 5 empty rows) you need to set both maxRows and minRows.

However, that would still allow the user to enter an unlimited length of text, only 5 rows of which will be visible at a time. To control the length of text, estimate how many characters (with spaces) would make up approx 5 rows and set `maxLength` prop on `inputProps`. Like so:

```js
<TextField
  maxRows={5}
  minRows={5}
  inputProps={{ maxLength: 50 }}
  multiline
  //  sx={{ maxWidth: 200 }}
/>
```

Comment: Max length is good, but there's important to block expanding textarea and content by fixed rows. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried my example above? The combination of `maxRows` and `maxLength` will block it from expanding to more than 5 rows.  You can further control the TextField, by setting a `maxWidth` on the component to ensure the size of each row is fixed:  `sx={{ maxWidth: 200 }}`

Comment: What about one letter in one row, is that equal 50 rows?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. The amount of letters that fit in one row depends on the width of your TextField and the fontSize used therein. In any case `maxLength` will always only be an estimate approximating what would fit in 5 (or x) rows...

Comment: @SamA. Somehow this didn't work for me I have below code  <TextField
            id="message"
            label="Message"
            multiline={true}
            rows={4}
            defaultValue={mainMessageText}
            InputProps={{
                maxLength: 100,
            }}
          />     I'm using MUI v5.11.12

Comment: @Dev what didn't work exactly? It's `inputProps` – not `InputProps`.

Answer (score 1):

if you use controlled value you can do something like

```
function onChange(event) {
    setState(event.currentTarget.value);
}

const tooLong = state?.split('\n').length ?? 0 > maxRows;
<TextField
    value={state}
    error={tooLong}
    maxRows={maxRows}
    onChange={onChange}
    helperText={tooLong ? `max. ${maxRows} lines` : undefined}
/>
```

Comment: little improvement "split(/\r?\n|\r|\n/g)"

Answer (score 0):

The short way would be to set `rows` to the desired number, like this:

```
<TextField multiline rows={5}/>
```

*NOTE*: I'm using `rows` instead of `maxRows`.

**MUI-Documentation:**
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#multiline

The multiline prop transforms the text field into a TextareaAutosize element. Unless the `rows` prop is set, the height of the text field dynamically matches its content (using TextareaAutosize). You can use the `minRows` and `maxRows` props to bound it.